# A error in your SQL syntax storing Google Maps

Tags: sql, joomla, syntax-error

We are building a Joomla website (using Community Builder for personal profiles). We want to store Google Maps coordinates. When a user register, the profile is stored in the database. But a message appears saying `'You have an error in your SQL syntax...'` We don't know what to do anymore.

Here is the code part:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO #__comprofiler (`cb_googlex`, `cb_googley`) WHERE `user_id`= \''. $userComplete->id .'\'
 VALUES ( \''.$mapCor['latitude'].'\', \''.$mapCor['longitude'].'\')';

$_CB_database->setQuery($query);
$_CB_database->loadResult();
```

Comment: `WHERE` doesn't make sense for `INSERT` statement

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of issues.

1) Are you inserting a new record or updating one? If you are inserting a new one then you don't need the `where` statement.

2) If you are updating an existing record then you need to use `SET` and not insert. And keep the `where` statement.

3) Finally, you are never executing that query. This is probably where your biggest problem is. YOu should be doing something like:

```
$_CB_database->setQuery($query);
$_CB_database->execute();
```

4) Finally, you should be using the query builder. Your life would be way easier. Try something like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true) // note true creates a new object

$updates = array('cb_googlex = ' . $mapCor['latitude'], 'cb_googley = ' . $mapCor['longitude']);

$conditions = array('user_id = ' . $userComplete->id);

$query->update($db->quoteName('#__comprofiler'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->query();
```

5) Debugging: Debugging DB queries is tough without working directly with SQL. My recommendation to you if this isn't working is to use the getQuery function and then actually copy / paste that query into something like phpMyAdmin and execute it there. The error you get will help you nail down any bugs much query. It works like this:

After you set the query with: $db->setQuery($query);

You can get the 'completed' query as a string:

```
$completed = $db->getQuery(); // notice I didn't pass the 'true' argument. That means it leaves the current query alone.
```

then do:

```
echo $completed;
```

You'll get the completed query in a string. Copy and paste it directly to your database utility like phpMyAdmin or SequelPro. You'll get a far more useful error and be able to correct your code.  You may need to manually replace the prefix.

Read more about inserting and updating records:

http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase